# how to write a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

This might be a broad question but I couldn't find a definite explanation on how to do this (maybe I am just not searching well enough).

I am writing a Chrome extension, that writes data I collect from a site about how many times the site has been visited (how many times the site has been clicked) and update to a database. The count should be shown before the site is opened when it is searched in Google.

The problem is that I really have no idea how to do this or where to start. It's my first Chrome extension, and on top of that it is the first time I ever use a database. A lot of firsts in this project :).

After googling, I found out that I probably have no idea how to use only javascript for writing the data into the database. But other than that, I am completely stumped and don't really know where to begin.

Any tips please?

Again, sorry if my question is too broad. Maybe this topic will help a future newbies (like me) get up to speed with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try your luck here https://crossrider.com/

Comment: Start from here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

Comment: thank u delueg and jslayer...but didnt find an appropriate example which is near to my idea of extension..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As told in comment, you should start by learning javascript and the basics of chrome extensions before starting a project like this. ([Get Started](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) and [API reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index))

I assume the principal question is: **How to send data from the extension back to your server?**

---

### Short Version

A solution is to use [AJAX requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) from the background page when you need to send data to the server.

### Detailed Version

1. Get the data you need from [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) when the user visits a page.
2. Send this data back to your background page through [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).
3. From your backgroud page Use [pure Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29#Example) or the [Jquery framework](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send the AJAX request. There are lots of question on this subject on stackoverflow.
4. Do not forget to set the correct permissions in your manifest.json file (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr).
5. Build a page (PHP, Java, etc.) on your server to recieve the POST data.

Comment: I added more details. I hope it will help you.

Comment: node is on the server. Chrome extension are on the client side. But yes yo can code the server side with node if you want. Thought I would recommend to use a PHP server. Apache is the best to handle large amounts of requests.